# PostgreSQL: Table that points to other Tables?

Tags: postgresql

Just getting started in PostgreSQL and wanted to ask some questions.
Suppose that I have a table of `Vendors`. Each `Vendors` has an attribute called `Sales Record`, which is a time series data about their sales. For each `Vendors`, I want to be one associated `Sales Record Table` that has the timeseries sales data for that specific vendor.

How might I want to code that?

Comment: I think you're looking for information about data modelling. Check this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a table per vendor.

Rather, create one big table for all. The table contains a column like `vendor_id` that is a foreign key to `vendors` and identifies to which vendor a record belongs.

If you create an index on `vendor_id`, searching the big table for the data of a vendor will be efficient.